# Deleting Sharepoint Site Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to delete a sharepoint site using powershell:

```
Remove-SPSite -Identity "site url"
```

I keep receiving an error message:

```
"Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url"
```

I am using sharepoint powershell on the sharepoint server using a farm user. I don't get anything when I run $StackTrace after the command. 
Thank you

Comment: Does Get-Spsite "url" gets you the site object ?

Comment: No it does not. I am able to get only the main site and also retrieve a list of all subsites. I only get this problem when I try to get or delete a subsite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon seeing your response to Guruparan's question, if you are trying to delete a subsite you need to use a different commandlet

```
Remove-SPWeb http://yourwebapp.example.com/sites/yoursite/yoursubsite
```

Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607890.aspx